# Extract pages in memory iTextSharp

Tags: c#

can someone help me with this problem. How can I extract some pages from pdf and return them as byte array or Stream, without using physical file as output.

Here is the way doing this using filestream:

```
public static void ExtractPages(string sourcePdfPath, string outputPdfPath, int      startPage, int endPage)
{

    PdfReader reader = null;
    Document sourceDocument = null;
    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;

   try
   {

    reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath);
    sourceDocument = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startPage));
    pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
    sourceDocument.Open();

        for(int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
        {
             importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
        }
        sourceDocument.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

I need something like:

```
public static byte[] ExtractPages(string sourcePdfPath, int startPage, int endPage)
{
....
    return byte[];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Replace the `new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create)` with a `MemoryStream` and return it.

Some thing like (untested, but should work):

```
public static byte[] ExtractPages(string sourcePdfPath, int startPage, int endPage)
{
    PdfReader reader = null;
    Document sourceDocument = null;
    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;
    MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();

    reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath);
    sourceDocument = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startPage));
    pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, target);
    sourceDocument.Open();

    for(int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
    {
        importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
        pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
    }
    sourceDocument.Close();
    reader.Close();

    return target.ToArray();
}
```